# How to open Xcode Projects on a Different Mac/Hard drive

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7

I recently got a new hard drive and reinstalled Mac OS X on it. I copied my entire folder with all my Xcode projects over. However when I tried booting up one by clicking the project file, Xcode opens up with only the project file present. All of the files with actual code on them are not appearing.

I tried to add files but even that would leave most of the files with code on them greyed out in the finder.

Question, what is the proper way of transferring these projects specifically in Xcode 7? I have not been able to find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1):

So, the only way I know of to do this efficiently is to load up the project file XML in your favorite editor and go manually fixup the paths.  I don't recommend this.

Unfortunately, the way to do it through the UI is for each file, you need to open the Utilities Bar on the right, select the file, then update the path via the little folder icon in the Identity and Type section.  Here's an illustration:

[image]

Then repeat for every file in your project.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue i mean you could always manually transfer code through word documents or notes, but for me i had copied the entire project folder and the document transferred just fine just make sure you transfer all of the files with it and not just the one file for the project itself

Answer (score -1):

delete the xcode application and reinstall it from the Mac App Store.